# How to make div 100% width when parent tag has padding?

Tags: html, css

I have an HTML page where the body tag has CSS padding-left and padding-right applied. I'd like the page footer div to be 100% width of the page though, without the body padding applied. Is there a good/easy way of doing this ?

Comment: You mean footer width = body.width + 10px + 10px?

Comment: Yeah I could do that with javascript, but I was thinking there was probably a CSS way I was missing too.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could apply a negative margin to the inside container to negate the padding

```
<body style="padding:0 40px">
<div style="width:100%;margin:0 -40px">&nbsp</div>
</body>
```

Comment: does not work if the elements need to be responsive (%-width)

Comment: For posterity.... the normal way this is achieved is `position: absolute; right: 0; left: 0;`

Comment: @Drenai it works but, if inside a td, it gets the width of the entire tr, instead of my td.

Comment: for me this worked https://stackoverflow.com/a/30894183/5864034

Answer (score 6):

If you give the footer a left and right margin that is a negative amount, of equal size to the padding of the body, then it will counter the body's padding.

```
body {
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-right:10px;
}
.footer {
    margin-left:-10px;
    margin-right:-10px;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative way can be this : using `calc`

```
<div class="parent"> <!--/ Parent div with padding left right -->
    <div class="child">i'm Child div</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.parent{
   padding:0 20px;
}
.child{
    width:-moz-calc(100% - 40px); <!--/ similar with other browser prefixes -->
    width:calc(100% - 40px);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

After some playing around, 'width: inherit;' solved it for me:

```
#parent-container {
  width: 400px; 
  padding: 0 15px;
}

#inner-div {
  width: inherit;
  margin: 0 -15px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is another way of solving this using `calc` on the parent element. That way, both the padding and the `calc` are in the same CSS class, and if the padding has to be modified you will see more easily that the `calc` formula has to be modified too than if it lies in the child element CSS class.

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 9;
  margin: 0;
}

.parent {
  width: calc(100% - 40px);    /* 40px: 2 * 20px padding */
  height: calc(100% - 50px);   /* 50px: 2 * 25px padding */
  padding: 25px 20px;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  background-color: tomato;
}

.child {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fbf7e5;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is the best answer in my opinion. There might be some issues with the exact example, but using calc on the parent is cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

When a `flexbox` layout used and a generic solution needed (say you do **not** want to be aware of the parent's padding sizes) the following shall be used (pay attention to the `box-sizing` property on parent:

```
.parent {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 48px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.child {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: the best solution I have to say, if you don't want to always know what is the padding

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that is for your case specifically, but i had a form (trying to code for responsive), width:100% and needed padding in inputfields so the solution was

```
form {
   margin: 0px 3%;
   width: 94%;
}
input:valid, textarea:valid {
   width: inherit;
   padding: 15px;
}
```

Inherit on fields just did the trick. (Only tested in chrome)

Update: noticed that this breaks graphical layout with some pixels, also here is a good illustration: http://theturninggate.net/2012/01/better-responsive-forms/